# How to generate an identical div to the right side of another div, onclick, and have it still be responsive

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked up a few things online but nothing has quite solved the issue I'm facing. I'm making a crypto currency API web app. I haven't connected the API yet because I simply want to solve this issue first.

The goal for now. When the user clicks the Magnifying glass it generates a new div with the Bitcoin info, *to the right* of the parent Bitcoin div. I am using bootstrap so ideally, each row would fill up with 4 Bitcoin divs. Once the row is filled the next row would begin to fill from left to right as before.

Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Crytocurreny Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     
 <!-- Search bar-->
  
  <section>
    <div class="container-fluid search">
       <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-12">
              <input type="search" placeholder="" class="text-uppercase"> 
              <i class="fas fa-search fa-2x" class="icon-unlock" id="magnifying-glass" onclick="newDiv()"></i>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </section>
     
 <!-- End of Search bar-->
     
 <!-- Crypto Divs --> 
 
     <section>
        <div class='container-fluid mt-5'>
           <div class='row mx-auto'>
              <div class='col-3'>
                 <div class='crypto-div p-3' max-width="280" id='crypto-div'>
                    <h1>Bitcoin</h1>
                    <p1>Price: $45,000</p1>
                    <br>
                    <p3 class='mt-3'>24hr high: $50,000</p3>
                    <br>
                    <p3 class='mt-3'>24hr low: $42,000</p3>
                    <br>
                    <p5>Ranking: 1</p5>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </section>
     
 <!-- End of Crypto Divs -->

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/886c2c3378.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-W8fXfP3gkOKtndU4JGtKDvXbO53Wy8SZCQHczT5FMiiqmQfUpWbYdTil/SxwZgAN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0;
}

body {
   background-color: #ffd480 !important;
}


/* Search Bar*/

.search {
   margin-top: 100px;
}


input {
   border: none;
   border-radius: 24px;
   padding: 10px;
   outline:none;
   font-size: 120% !important;
   color: #818181;
   font-color: ;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color:;
   transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

input:hover{
   transition: all .4s ease-in;
   transform: scale(1.07);
   background-color: #01A08B;
   color: white;
}
/* End of Search Bar*/

/* Magnifying glass icon*/

i{
   color: white;
   margin-left: px;
   transition: all .3s ease-out;
   padding: 4px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin-left: 10px;
}

i:hover {
   transition: all .3s ease-in;
   cursor: pointer;
   transform: scale(1.2);
   color: #01A08B;
}
/* end of Magnifying glass icon*/



/*Universal Crypto Div*/

.crypto-div{
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color:white;
   color: #01A08B;
   border-radius: 20px;
   max-width: 280px;
   min-width: 200px;
   transition: all .4s ease-out;
   
}

.crypto-div:hover {
 transition: all .4s ease-in;
   transform: scale(1.07);
   background-color: #01A08B;
   color: white;
   cursor:pointer;
 
}

/* End of Universal Crypto Div*/

/* new div thats generated */

.new-div{
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color:white;
   color: #01A08B;
   border-radius: 20px;
   max-width: 100px;
   min-width: 200px;
   transition: all .4s ease-out;
   
}


.new-div:hover {
 transition: all .4s ease-in;
   transform: scale(1.07);
   background-color: #01A08B;
   color: white;
   cursor:pointer;
 
}

/*  end of new div thats generated */
```

JavaScript

```
//my attempt at creating a div generator 

function newDiv() {

   let div = document.createElement('div')
   
   div.className ="new-div";
   
   div.innerHTML = "<div class='p-3 mt-3 mx-auto' id='crypto-div'><h1>Bitcoin</h1><p1>Price: $45,000 </p1><br><p3 class='mt-3'>24hr high:$50,000 </p3><br><p3 class='mt-3'>24hr low: $42,000</p3><br><p5>Ranking: 1 </p5></div>";
   
   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get it... Is the problem that the generated div is not next to the already existing div? If the problem is that, just put an ID to your row for example id="parent" and then instead of

**document.body.appendChild(div);**

make

**let parent = document.getElementById('parent')

parent.appendChild(div)**

Comment: Yes exactly. It appears below the div but not to the right of the div

Comment: Did the code I gave to you solved your problem?

Comment: “`I did not get it.`”, well, why are you answering?

Comment: Well because is free and I lose $ 0.00 to answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So this did not solve my issue as the div element is still appearing below the div and not besides it. Thank you for trying though. I learned something new :)

Comment: Bro, please take a look: https://uhpum.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

My personal suggestion if you already know the html and all the information inside is to add a `display` and `visibility` element to the div you want hidden/shown in CSS then have the click function change the `display` and `visibility` property for it to be seen. This should help make styling easier in the future too if needed.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Crytocurreny Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     
 <!-- Search bar-->
  
  <section>
    <div class="container-fluid search">
       <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-12">
              <input type="search" placeholder="" class="text-uppercase"> 
              <i class="fas fa-search fa-2x" class="icon-unlock" id="magnifying-glass" onclick="showNewDiv()"></i>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </section>
     
 <!-- End of Search bar-->
     
 <!-- Crypto Divs --> 
 
     <section>
        <div class='container-fluid mt-5'>
           <div class='row mx-auto'>
              <div class='col-3'>
                 <div class='crypto-div p-3' max-width="280" id='crypto-div'>
                    <h1>Bitcoin</h1>
                    <p1>Price: $45,000</p1>
                    <br>
                    <p3 class='mt-3'>24hr high: $50,000</p3>
                    <br>
                    <p3 class='mt-3'>24hr low: $42,000</p3>
                    <br>
                    <p5>Ranking: 1</p5>
                 </div>
                 <div class='p-3 mt-3 mx-auto' id='crypto-div2'>
                     <h1>Bitcoin</h1>
                     <p1>Price: $45,000 </p1>
                     <br>
                     <p3 class='mt-3'>24hr high:$50,000 </p3>
                     <br>
                     <p3 class='mt-3'>24hr low: $42,000</p3>
                     <br>
                     <p5>Ranking: 1 </p5>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </section>
     
 <!-- End of Crypto Divs -->





    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/886c2c3378.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-W8fXfP3gkOKtndU4JGtKDvXbO53Wy8SZCQHczT5FMiiqmQfUpWbYdTil/SxwZgAN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function showNewDiv() {
    newDiv = document.getElementById('crypto-divs2');
    newDiv.style.display = 'block';
    newDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
   
}
```

CSS

```
#crypto-div2{
   display: hidden;
   visibility: none;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color:white;
   color: #01A08B;
   border-radius: 20px;
   max-width: 100px;
   min-width: 200px;
   transition: all .4s ease-out;
   
}


#crypto-div2:hover {
 transition: all .4s ease-in;
   transform: scale(1.07);
   background-color: #01A08B;
   color: white;
   cursor:pointer;
 
}
```

**Edit**: Alternate JS file and suggestion adding an id to the div where you want the new div to be created and changing the JS.

JS

```
function newDiv() { 
   let firstDiv = document.getElementById('div-id-to-append'); 

   let div = document.createElement('div'); 
   div.className ="new-div"; 
   div.innerHTML = "<div class='p-3 mt-3 mx-auto' id='crypto-div'> 
      <h1>Bitcoin</h1><p1>Price: $45,000 </p1><br><p3 class='mt- 
      3'>24hr high:$50,000 </p3><br><p3 class='mt-3'>24hr low: 
      $42,000</p3><br><p5>Ranking: 1 </p5></div>";

   firstDiv.appendChild(div); 
}
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the reply. I like this suggestions, but my inerhent issue is that this will be soon connected to an API with almost an infinite amount of cyrpto currencies. It makes more sense in my mind to have a function that creates divs on command then repeating code to many times. I will keep this in min however if i dont find a solution :)

Comment: I edited the answer to try and accommodate what you asked for. Let me know if that helps at all.